# How to Determine when a user was given permission to a site or list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm looking to see if there is a way in powershell or some other method to determine when a user was given permission to a site or list and/or who granted the user permission. I have ran the effective user permission reports and can see the group/groups that this user is part of that grants them permissions. I have checked the audit logs but unfortunately auditing only goes back a year. So I didn't know if there was a way to see something like a date added for permission or if there was a way to query the database to retrieve this information.